# "Transform the expression" where we have to transform the given infix expression to postfix expression

Tags: c++, switch-statement, stack, postfix-mta, infix-notation

All sample cases have passed but when I submit it shows wrong answer though I have programmed the
logic well.
Can someone tell me some test cases where my code is giving wrong answer. I think I have programmed my
logic according to what I have been taught at my school. Please I am very tensed, someone help me.
Link to question:https://www.spoj.com/problems/ONP/

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;

void post_fix(string exp)
{
    stack<char> s;
    for(int i=0;i<exp.length();i++)
    {
        switch (exp[i])
        {
        case '+':
            while(s.top()=='*'||s.top()=='-'||s.top()=='/'||s.top()=='^')
            {
                cout<<s.top();
                s.pop();
            }
            s.push(exp[i]);
            break;
        
        case '-':
            while(s.top()=='*'||s.top()=='/'||s.top()=='^')
            {
                cout<<s.top();
                s.pop();
            }
            s.push(exp[i]);
            break;

        case '*':
            while(s.top()=='/'||s.top()=='^')
            {
                cout<<s.top();
                s.pop();
            }
            s.push(exp[i]);
            break;

        case '/':
            while(s.top()=='^')
            {
                cout<<s.top();
                s.pop();
            }
            s.push(exp[i]);
            break;

        case '^':
            s.push(exp[i]);
            break;

        case '(':
            s.push('(');
            break;

        case ')':
            while(s.top()!='(')
            {
                cout<<s.top();
                s.pop();
            }
            s.pop();
            break;

        default:
            cout<<exp[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    while(!s.empty())
    {
        cout<<s.top();
        s.pop();
    }
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        string exp;
        cin>>exp;
        post_fix(exp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The example in the question says that `(a+(b*c))` should become `abc*+` but your program gives `c*b+a`.  Also, you probably need newlines between your answers for it to pass the online judge.

Comment: No,my answer is correct I missed the newline that's why the fault was coming.Many mant thanks @TedLyngmo for your help.I am really very grateful to you. Regards

Comment: :-) Oh, glad it was of help!